# Trouble proving Wigner function identity

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dirac-delta-distributions, coherent-states, wigner-transform

I am trying to prove $$\int d^2 \alpha W(\alpha)=1$$ where $W(\alpha)$ represents the Wigner funcion. However, I have trouble solving it. I tried solving it as follows but I think I have done  some mistake. I have also attached a screenshot of the book page (Quantum Optics by Girish S. Agarwal Section $1.7$) from which I am doing this derivation. Kindly tell me what am I doing wrong here?

$$ W(\alpha) = \int d^2 \beta Tr[\rho D(\beta)] \exp(-(\beta \alpha^* -\beta^* \alpha)) $$
$$\int W(\alpha) d^2 \alpha = \int \int d^2 \alpha d^2 \beta Tr[\rho D(\beta)] \exp(-(\beta \alpha^* -\beta^* \alpha)) $$
$\alpha$ is a complex parameter and by using the identity $\delta(x)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(\iota k x) dk $, we can write
$$\int d\alpha e^{\beta^* \alpha}= 2 \pi \delta(\beta^*)$$
$$\int d\alpha^* e^{-\beta \alpha^*}= 2\pi \delta(-\beta).$$
Now
$$\int d^2 \alpha e^{-(\beta \alpha^* -\beta^* \alpha)} =\int d\alpha e^{\beta^* \alpha}\int d\alpha^* e^{-\beta \alpha^*} = 4 \pi^2\delta(\beta^*) \delta(-\beta) $$
At this point, I think I have done it wrong because I am not getting my 2D dirac delta function here.

[image: Introductory Quantum Optics]

Comment: Which book? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic The book is Quantum Optics by Girish S. Agarwal. There are no page numbers in my pdf file however the section is 1.7

Comment: Have you parsed out your complex variables in terms of real ones that you may use the δ definitions on? You are worried about the  $4\pi^2$ factor?

Comment: [This](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4985938) might be useful.